# How to get strongly-typed collection from XML using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Here's a snippet from my XML file (I realize its format isn't ideal, but I unfortunately cannot change it):

```
<PRODMENUS>
<MENU id="90168" shortname="BrdSumPV13" mealname="Dinner" mealid="7" servedate="20130102">Summer PREV 2013</MENU>
<MENU id="90153" shortname="BrdSumPV13" mealname="Breakfast" mealid="46" servedate="20130102">Summer PREV 2013</MENU>
<MENU id="90162" shortname="BrdSumPV13" mealname="Lunch" mealid="6" servedate="20130102">Summer PREV 2013</MENU>
</PRODMENUS>
```

The following function works, but it only grabs the first menu element, but not the rest

```
public static List<Menu> GetLocations(string uri)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
    var menus = from menu in xmlDoc.Elements("PRODMENUS")
                          select new Menu
                          {
                              Id = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Element("MENU").Attribute("id").Value),
                              ShortName = menu.Element("MENU").Attribute("shortname").Value,
                              MealName = menu.Element("MENU").Attribute("mealname").Value,
                              MealId = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Element("MENU").Attribute("mealid").Value)
                          };

    return menus.ToList();
}
```

How can I get a collection of 3 Menu objects using the above XML file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are very close

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
var menus = from menu in xmlDoc.Descendants("MENU")
            select new Menu
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Attribute("id").Value),
                ShortName = menu.Attribute("shortname").Value,
                MealName = menu.Attribute("mealname").Value,
                MealId = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Attribute("mealid").Value)
            };

return menus.ToList();
```

you can also use some shortcuts like `Id = (int)menu.Attribute("id")` instead of `Id = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Attribute("id").Value)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to go 1 level deeper and do `xmlDoc.Elements("PRODMENUS").Elements("MENU")`

```
var menus = from menu in xmlDoc.Elements("PRODMENUS").Elements("MENU")
            select new Menu
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Attribute("id").Value),
                ShortName = menu.Attribute("shortname").Value,
                MealName = menu.Attribute("mealname").Value,
                MealId = Convert.ToInt32(menu.Attribute("mealid").Value)
            };
```